# Generate ID based on file and line in (or something similar)

Tags: php, identifier

In my program I need a way to create unique identifiers (like hash).  It is important that IDs were not random, but the same between calls a the same function or method. Thus, if in some line in some file is generated identifier `xyz`, then always in this place should be generated the same identifier.

I could use code such instruction:

```
$id = sha1(__FILE__ . __ LINE__);
```

But this not enough comfortable. I'd prefer to use some function or macro like in C/C++ (I know that PHP does not have macros) as follows:

```
$id = generate_id();
```

The `generate_id` could be implemented as below. It works fine, but  I'm not convinced to use the function `debug_backtrace` in production code. Maybe there's a better solution?

```
function generate_id()
{
   $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
   return sha1($backtrace[0]['file'] . $backtrace[0]['line']);
}
```

Comment: The way you are doing it should be fine.  The alternative being `generate_id(__FILE__, __ LINE__)`

Comment: It works? For me, it return parse error.

Comment: Well, you have to use it in an assignment with a `;` and also change your function to accept parameters, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to have a repeatable hash based on a file, PHP has the [md5_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) method which should do what you need.

```
$file = 'myfile.txt';
echo 'MD5 file hash of ' . $file . ': ' . md5_file($file);
```

As long as the file contents do not change, the MD5 hash will be the same each time you generate it.

Comment: Alternatively, he needs the md5 to repeatable regardless of change, he can do `md5(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)`

Comment: Except they want an id based on the **file** AND the **line** in the file from where the id is generated.

Comment: This is not exactly this what I want. In one file I want generate many ID's. Your solutions based on my first example: `$id = sha1(__FILE__ . __ LINE__);` and it is not enough comfortable for me. I would rather one function without any argument like `generate_id`.